# read XLS file through batch script

Tags: windows, excel, batch-file

This works:-

```
for /F  "tokens=4 delims=    skip=1" %%x in (myfile.txt) DO echo %%x
```

But not this:-

```
for /F  "tokens=4 delims=    skip=1" %%x in (myfile.xls) DO echo %%x
```

How can i read xls without converting to tab saperated?

XLS = Excel file

Comment: The title of your question is wrong... are you talking about XML or XLS?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it with batch, for whatever reasons, you can export and save your xls file to comma separated (csv), then use delim=, in your batch for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you're talking about the binary .xls format *or* XML, parsing in a Windows batch file is basically going to be impractical. You should use a more appropriate tool. The closest thing to a Windows batch file which will be able to cope with this is probably [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell).

Batch files are okay for pretty simple tasks, but when you need to do anything with a bit more complexity, you should look to use something more powerful. (I'm not particularly fond of Windows batch files in the first place compared with, say, bash scripts - but sometimes they're the easiest way to get things done.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel installed, you can easily create a vbscript or PowerShell script for the task.  The Windows command shell interpreter really isn't up to the task of parsing Excel files.

VBScript:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

[PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/09/08/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-automate-microsoft-excel.aspx):

```
a = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
```